# Running A Simulation That Yields Close, but off significantly in some areas

Tags: r

So I am running a simulation for baseball team wins. I have a formula that will give me away team and home team odds. It looks like this (MLB_3 is the name of the df)

```
 X2021 Away_Team Home_Team Away_Team_Odds Home_Team_Odds
1 1-Apr Blue.Jays   Yankees       46.85205       53.14795
2 3-Apr Blue.Jays   Yankees       46.85205       53.14795
3 4-Apr Blue.Jays   Yankees       46.85205       53.14795
4 5-Apr   Orioles   Yankees       33.63985       66.36015
5 6-Apr   Orioles   Yankees       33.63985       66.36015
6 7-Apr   Orioles   Yankees       33.63985       66.36015
```

So I projected a Winner by adding

```
MLB_3$RN <- runif(2430,0,100)

MLB_3$Winner <- ifelse(MLB_3$RN > MLB_3$Away_Team_Odds, yes = MLB_3$Home_Team, no = MLB_3$Away_Team)
```

With 2430 being the total amount of games. They are all distinct and the schedule is correct I am sure.

I want to sim it 25000 times and get the average number of wins per team

So I ran this

```
set.seed(100)

Sims <- replicate(n = 25000, expr = sample(MLB_3$Winner, 2340)) 
Sims <- as.data.frame(Sims)

Proj <- Sims %>% 
  gather("key", "value", V1:V25000) %>% 
  group_by(value) %>% 
  summarise(Wins = round(n() / 25000,1)) %>% 
  arrange(-Wins)
```

And it gave me what I wanted, but based on their scores and odds the data does not make sense. I expected some variation from what I initially thought, but the 3rd best team in terms of odds has the 6th most wins, and the 6th best team has 16th most wins.

So I wanted to put the code out to see if anyone knows why I am getting these results, or if I missed something in my code.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Odds or probabilities? Is this a logistic regression model?

Comment: I'm not sure your `replicate` call is doing what you expect. It's not re-running the season and applying new `MLB_3$RN`, it's rather sampling without replacement from the WINS, so it seems to be reshuffling one run of the same data.

Comment: @JonSpring Ah that would make a whole lotta sense. Do you have any suggestions on how I could re-sim the season? I'm quite new at this, and usually just use excel for it.

Comment: @BillO'Brien the Away Team Odds are the probability that the team will win, so I guess it is logistic bc its Win/Loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the simulation by creating a function.

```
sim <- function(MLB_3) {
  MLB_3$RN <- runif(nrow(MLB_3),0,100)
  transform(MLB_3, Winner = ifelse(RN > Away_Team_Odds, Home_Team, Away_Team))
}
```

and use `replicate` to repeat it `n` times and perform the calculation.

```
n <- 25000
replicate(n, sim(MLB_3), simplify = FALSE) %>%
  dplyr::bind_rows(.id = 'sim_number') -> data

data
```